# How to restrict Save As in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, save-as

How to restrict save web page?

Right Click & Print is done, but Save As Page is not working in browser.

Is there any solution for save page in browser?

Please help for restrict page by using JavaScript or jQuery or any solution.

Comment: You can't. This is one of internal options of the browser.

Comment: You can't, once a user has viewed a page, it's stored in the temporary files on their computer. Save As simply makes a copy of that file, so by viewing a page, they've essentially saved it. Although I do look forward to your next challenge of asking all keyboard manufacturers to remove the 'Print Screen' button

Comment: Its internal options of the browser. We can do print & copy text restrict as well as we hides context menu. Why it is not get any event for "Save As" menu item??
@MLeFevre We are also trying remove thr 'Print Screen' It is not possible to remove it. We got key event but we cant find key value of printscreen. If it is got then will try to remove clipboard data.

Comment: @MLeFevre This is a forum to discuss the thing not to crack jokes on others
I ll not ask to remove the  'Print Screen' button to keyboard manufactures because after that hw will u people take print :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does worry me when people's first response is *"impossible"*, especially as you said "any solution" :)

If you are serious about preventing the saving of text content, you can use Flash or Silverlight to display it, so that it is not rendered as text by the browser.

This way your content is protected from all text copying (except screen-grabbing is still possible).

It would help if you explain the purpose of your requirement as Flash/Silverlight are not good options for mobile devices (which generally do not support them).

Comment: That is indeed a possibility, but is bad for your SEO

Comment: @Ruub: I think we can safely assume that SEO is not a factor if they are going to these lengths to hide their page content :) Being able to simply Google their secret information would be "bad".

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Given a your solution is implemented for pdf, We are using Flash, but we cant do for text and images because of every important page can't do this. SEO is not factor if it is got good solution for restrict save page.